# How getstream handle share feature like facebook

Tags: getstream-io

How to implement share like feature (like facebook) in getstream. Is it handled by getstream or we have to handle it at our own. I am using laravel framework.

Comment: can you add more detail? what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i want to share my feed. do i have to handle it localy or there is any way to know through getstream which feed is shared

Comment: could you please help on this

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning GetStream, but here is how I would approach a "share" feature in GetStream.

In your comment you mentioned you wanted to "share my feed".  I don't think you can share your feed.  Other people can follow your feed, but you can't share it.

In Facebook, users can "share" a post.  Then there are options to share on your timeline, as a message, to another feed, etc.

In regards to GetStream, you can share an Activity (or message) to another feed.  That's about as far as I can go with this.  Hope this helps.